# How to make a combobox in excel autocomplete numbers?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have comboboxes in userforms that fill with part numbers taken from a named range in a sheet.
`comboxPartNumber.List = Range("Part_Number").Value`

The combobox will auto-complete anything with a letter or a hyphen, Like KO-5000 or 766-500 but it will not auto-complete any actual numbers like 766500 or 75100. I tried formatting the cells in the named range to be used as text values even if they are a number but that didn't work. When a selection is made in the combobox it autofills other textboxes with part information, and when I type in a part number that is only numbers (766500), it will auto fill all the necessary information, I just can't get the autocomplete in the combobox to work for numbers. If anyone could help me out I'd appreciate it, I can give you any other code you may need.

Thanks ALOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Combobox will autocomplete numbers also, if they are stored in Cells of a Range, that is the RowSource of the Combobox.

Try:

```
comboxPartNumber.RowSource = "Part_Number"
```

Greetings

Axel